# SuiteCloud IDE 2.3.3 is slow

Tags: eclipse, performance, ide, netsuite, scriptlet

I've been using the **Eclipse SuiteCloud IDE** for months. Recently I've been getting timeouts and errors when simply trying to upload files to the *SANDBOX* environment (*PRODUCTION* seems better).

I've also been getting slow response times when calling restlets with Fiddler but not sure the two are connected.

I've tried clearing the cache and using the garbage collector in Eclipse but nothing really seems to improve the situation.

If I use the Netsuite interface to view or edit my scripting files, it is almost instant.

Any ideas why this might be happening or what I can do to fix the situation?

Many thanks

Don

Comment: As an alternate you can use https://suitecoder.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sandboxes can be a bit slow. Unfortunately, I don't have a great answer for your issue, other than to call NetSuite support and voice your concern.

Comment: Thanks, I've logged a ticket but just thought I can't be the only one who can't use the sandbox. We pay for the service too which makes me wonder what exactly are we getting...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of sub folders and also number of files in your suitescript filecabinet.
Try to move other folders / files outside SuiteScripts folder, such as log file if you have any.